# floating widgets (similar to i-google/bbc.co.uk )

Tags: jquery, widget, html, floating

I want to mimic one behavior of the two sites - that of floating widgets - where a user can reorganize the layout.  How is that accomplished? Is there any jquery modules available for that? It would be really great if someone could point me to those resources..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqueryui sortables could work for you: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets